# Insert Items dynamically in a QListWidget

Tags: c++, sql, qt

What I would like to do is taking input from a sql database and put all these datas in a QListWidget, but I don't know how many of them there gonna be, I need also to know the id of which one was clicked when clicked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if str is the label from your sql query and n is the id then:

create your items with:

```
QListWidgetItem* i = new QListWidgetItem(str);
```

Set the id with:

```
i->setData(Qt::UserRole, n);
```

and add it to the widget:

```
myListWidget->addItem(i);
```

Then when its clicked you will get the signal

```
void QListWidget::itemActivated ( QListWidgetItem * item ) [signal]
```

connect this to a slot in your class and get the id back with

```
item->data(Qt::UserRole).toInt();
```

But this is also a good time to use QTableView and QSqlQueryModel.

Comment: Would QTableView a better use in this case?

Comment: QTableWidget in Qt4 is the closest thing to QListView in Qt3. Its much quicker to get going with the Widget classes than the View classes but the View classes are pretty cool, and if you don't need to edit the sql table in-line in the view, QTableView and QSqlQueryModel together might be your best bet.

Comment: I agree with you, it's what I was looking for but do you know how I link an id to a row without having to show it.

I want to have a QTableView showing category, but not their id, but i want to use the id in my program so they have to be linked

Comment: probably easiest to just hide the index column http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#hideColumn

Comment: By the way, I knew they had done something like QSqlQueryModel but hadn't really looked at it. I'm going to try it too - thanks for asking the question. And if you have only a single table there is an editable version of the model too. Cool.